# Recommended shopping cart: Paypal Payment Pro Integrate into existing site

Tags: php, paypal, shopping-cart

I ve done research on various shopping carts for way too long now, but I can't seem to find a shopping cart that is SIMPLE, LIGHT-WEIGHT, and easy to INTEGRATE into my existing website. I will have PayPal website pro and want to give the user the option to pay at my site or through paypal.

Does anybody have any recommendation for such a shopping cart (open source/commercial)? Please if you do, let me know! I don't want to hand code bc 1.) I don't want to reinvent the wheel and 2.) I probably wouldn't make it as secure as it should

It's also important to mention that I would ideally like to use just one database for my website. I already have the databases setup for users, so whatever the shopping cart, it should fit/blend right into my website design AND also give enough flexibility to integrate with existing database tables.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many, many open source solutions that offer integrations into many payment gateways.

However, depending on where you see your site going over the next few years it may pay to write PayPal Payments integration yourself, you don't have to provide secure pages as PPP will drop out into the PayPal site to authenticate etc. the payment following that is handled between your server and PayPals.  PayPal also have lots of sample code for different web technologies that will help - you may find it an invaluable experience writing your own cart/payment etc.

If you want an out of the box solution then you may find it difficult to get one that will simply slide into your existing setup, plus given the inbuilt complexities with online payments they will never be truly *simple*.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Yes, you're completely right. I ended up using an open source js script for the shopping cart mechanism. I tweaked it to allow for validation on the server side before submitting to PayPal. I am also going to look into integrating payments on my site using the PayPal DoDirectPayment so customers can have various ways of paying. Thanks for the tips.